# Do you ever need to pay to obtain all the achievements in Warframe?

Tags: achievements, warframe

There seems to be a lot of weapon mastery related achievements... Is it possible to get all the achievements in this game without ever paying a cent?

Comment: Partial answer: technically, no. Everything that's needed can be obtained by playing the game. Even platinum can be exchanged directly with other players, so if you _do_ end up needing some, you can try to trade some mods for it. However, I'm not sure if mastery achievements require all the weapons/warframes to be in your inventory at the same time, or if you can sell them and still get credit.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann There are no achievements that require platinum.

Comment: @memescientist Not directly. I was referring to inventory expansions primarily. If you can sell items and still get credit for obtaining and levelling them, then you're right.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann Yeah, as long as you get your weapons/frames to Rank 30 before you sell, you'll get all the mastery points and fufill some parts of achievements.  Some achievements are actually unobtainable, specifically the Mastery Rank achievements, but you'll see that others have them, which means they used Steam Achievement Manager for it

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to.  Any achievement in game can be obtained naturally or manually (SAM).

Even though you have a very limited amount of weapon slots and frame slots, leveling each frame/weapon to 30 is simple, provided you sell each frame and weapon as you go along.